# Which NMDS axes should I plot?

Tags: r, distance, ggplot2, vegan

I have been running some non-metric multidimensional scaling analysis on a bray-curtis dissimilarity matrix (using `ecodist::distance()`). Theory suggests that we choose $k$ number of dimensions to run our ordinations (nmds analysis). However, this value of $k$ will vary from use case to use case.

From this [source](http://strata.uga.edu/8370/lecturenotes/multidimensionalScaling.html), we know that NMDS begins by constructing an initial configuration of the samples in the $k$ dimensions. This initial configuration could be based on another ordination or it could consist of an entirely random placement of the samples. The distances among samples in this starting configuration are calculated, typically with a Euclidean metric. These distances are regressed against the original distance matrix and the predicted ordination distances for each pair of samples is calculated. In a perfect ordination, all ordinated distances would fall exactly on the regression, that is, they would match the rank order of distances in the original distance matrix. The goodness of fit of the regression is measured as the sum of squared differences between ordination-based distances and the distances predicted by the regression. This goodness-of-fit is known as 'stress'.

A rule-of-thumb suggests stress $< 0.05$ provides an excellent representation in reduced dimensions, $< 0.1$ is great, $< 0.2$ is good/ok, and stress $< 0.3$ provides a poor representation.

In my study, I have ~100 columns, each representing a particular species, and the rows correspond to the number of detections of a particular species. Following the creation of a bray-curtis dissimilarity matrix, I ran the following code, trying to identify which value of $k$ leads to a least stressed configuration:

#### Run nmds using the `ecodist::nmds()` function that examines $X$ number of dimensions (I provided 6 dimensions)

```
# Please note this function is a time-consuming process
nmdsBrayCurtis <- nmds(disBrayCurtis, nits=100, mindim=1, maxdim=6)

# Pulling out the stress values into a 6x100 matrix
nmdsStress <- matrix(nmdsBrayCurtis$stress, nrow=6, byrow=T)
(nmdsStressMean <- apply(nmdsStress, 1, "mean"))
[1] 0.53929533 0.23070030 0.17467337 0.14115151 0.11602319 0.09535922
(nmdsStressMin <- apply(nmdsStress, 1, "min"))
[1] 0.5063341 0.2184086 0.1692578 0.1379154 0.1135408 0.0929492
(nmdsStressMax <- apply(nmdsStress, 1, "max"))
[1] 0.56729443 0.29886285 0.18212177 0.14702946 0.12030292 0.09986081
```

You will notice above that I provided $k=1$ to $k=6$ to test what dimensions lead to a least stressed configuration and in this case, $k=6$ leads to very low stress.

#### Scree plot of the stresses

```
plot(1:6, nmdsStressMean, type="b", pch=19, lwd=2, xlab="Dimensions",xlim = c(0,6), ylim=c(0, 1), ylab="Stress")
lines(1:6, nmdsStressMin, type="l", lty=2)
lines(1:6, nmdsStressMax, type="l", lty=2)
title("NMDS Stepdown Stress Plot")
```

[image]

This plot suggests a maximum drop in stress from 1 to say ~3 dimensions and then it plateaus around 4 to 5 dimensions. So I ran a final NMDS run with $k=6$ dimensions

```
nmdsBrayCurtis <- nmds(disBrayCurtis, mindim=6,maxdim=6, nits=100)

nmdsPower <- nmds.min(nmdsBrayCurtis, dims=6)
Minimum stress for given dimensionality:  0.09295401 
r^2 for minimum stress configuration:  0.8267929
```

The above variable stores this dataframe that comprises ordination scores for 6 dimensions

[image]

So my question now is, should I assume that Axis 1 and Axis 2 have the highest explanatory power and plot them using ggplot2? or what axes do I plot? I do realize that NMDS is not an eigenanalysis technique like principal components analysis or correspondence analysis. As a result, the axes cannot be interpreted such that axis 1 explains the greatest amount of variance, axis 2 explains the next greatest amount of variance, and so on. But if plot different axes, I get different interpretations of the data, so which one is the 'right' one? I am showing you two examples - one which considers Axis 1 and Axis 2 and another which considers Axis 1 and Axis 5.

Axis 1 and Axis 5

[image]

Axis 1 and Axis 2

[image]

Looking for a good statistical explanation.

Comment: Your stress scree-plot suggests to me that 2, maximum 3, dimensions will suffice. Why are you choosing 6? Why not 16 (the stress in normally expected to lower slowly further with the number of dimensions).

Comment: @ttnphns Why would you say that 2/3 dimensions would suffice? Is it because I am not gaining any significant reduction in stress post 2 dimensions?

Comment: @Vijay Ramesh ... I'm a bit late here but either way if OP were to use 3 dimensions how should they go about plotting that?